# Does compiling nginx with "--with-debug" option reduce performance even when not enabling debug level?

Tags: nginx

I want to build nginx with the debug options and use it in production.
But the instructions provided here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html do not say if it will have performance issues even when I **DON'T** enable **debug** level logging.

The reason to build nginx with debug options is to quickly debug any issues that come up in production rather than patching nginx after building it again. It reduces one painful step.